# Determine which 'oneof' proto3 field is set in C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, proto3

For the following Protocol Buffer message (proto3) how to I determine which type is set? There does not seem to be a "has_reply" method as is the case for the generated C++ version.

```
message Event {
  oneof type {
    Connection connection = 1;
    StatusReply reply = 2;
    Error error = 3;
    End end = 4;
    Empty empty = 5;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp-generated#oneof suggests that `TypeOneofCase` will tell you which is set:

> #### Oneof Fields
>
> Each field within a oneof has a separate property, like a regular
>   singular field. However, the compiler also generates an additional
>   property to determine which field in the enum has been set, along with
>   an enum and a method to clear the oneof. For example, for this oneof
>   field definition
>
> ```
> oneof avatar {
>   string image_url = 1;
>   bytes image_data = 2;
> }
> ```
>
> The compiler will generate these public members:
>
> ```
> enum AvatarOneofCase
> {
>   None = 0,
>   ImageUrl = 1,
>   ImageData = 2
> }
>
> public AvatarOneofCase AvatarCase { get; }
> public void ClearAvatar();
> public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
> public ByteString ImageData { get; set; }
> ```
>
> If a property is the current oneof "case", fetching that property will
>   return the value set for that property. Otherwise, fetching the
>   property will return the default value for the property's type - only
>   one member of a oneof can be set at a time.
>
> Setting any constituent property of the oneof will change the reported
>   "case" of the oneof. As with a regular singular field, you cannot set
>   a oneof field with a string or bytes type to a null value. Setting a
>   message-type field to null is equivalent to calling the oneof-specific
>   Clear method.

Comment: > Otherwise, fetching the property will return the default value for the property's type - only one member of a oneof can be set at a time.

This is awful! Default value and not set are not the same! This essentially makes the C# implementation oneof useless.

Comment: @IsenGrim What is the alternative though (i.e. how would you build it otherwise)? `ImageUrl` is a `string` - so it fundamentally needs to return something that is actually a `string` - it can't return something else. The key bit here is to read the `AvatarCase` property before deciding whether to read `ImageUrl` or `ImageData`.